# How to have the correct checkboxes checked for an edit page from mySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a1">Used e-mail
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a2">Used instant messenger & chat room
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a3">Made a purchase for personal use
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a4">Downloaded/Played a video game
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a5">Obtained news/information
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a6">Looked for employment
```

On submit I use

```
$q1=implode(',', $_POST['q1']);
```

and then save it into a mySQL DB like a1,a3,a5

My question now is that I have an edit page, where I know how to show the value from DB using textboxes. I do not know how to have the correct checkboxes checked.

I know that it is good to use explode and create an array from the saved values. I know that there is a PHP way but I found this code for a dropdown and it helps not to have php if statements to every checkbox.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
       window.onload = function(){
          document.getElementsByName("year")[0].value="2008";  // change the value to the open obtained from database 
       }
      </script>
```

How can I do this for the checkboxes? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can interate your checkboxes with `for` loop and check if that input value exists in the array from db with `indexOf`:

```
window.onload = function(){    
    var dbdata = "a1,a3,a4"; //this should come from db
    dbdata = dbdata.split(",");
    for(i = 0; i<document.getElementsByName("q1[]").length;i++)
    {
        obj = document.getElementsByName("q1[]");
        if(dbdata.indexOf(obj[i].value) > -1)
        obj[i].checked=true; 
    }
}
```

working example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62Tke/)